# Selecting options in form drop down using watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I have a form that I am trying to select some drop down options using watir. I am having trouble finding the correct way to select these options (in this case "bob") using watir. Any suggestions?

```
<form action="blahsome.php" method="post">
<select onchange="clearFields();" size="1" name="credential">
<option>tom</option>
<option>bob</option>
<option>susan</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [Select#select](http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Select#select-instance_method):

```
browser.select_list(:name => 'credential').select('bob')
```

The value passed to `select` can be a string or regular expression that matches the options text or label.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the delay answering back. But this worked great. Thanks!